# Vec mutability mismatch after collect

Tags: rust

I have the following:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = vec![];
    let mut bar = vec![1, 2].iter().map(|a| a + 1).collect::<Vec<_>>();
    foo.append(&bar);
}
```

When I run the code snippet, Rust complains about `bar` not being mutable:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:4:16
  |
4 |     foo.append(&bar);
  |                ^^^^ types differ in mutability
  |
  = note: expected mutable reference `&mut std::vec::Vec<_>`
                     found reference `&std::vec::Vec<_>`
```

As I understand it, I need to have a mutable reference to the `Vec` I am trying to append, as the type signature for [`Vec::append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.append) is:

> ```
> fn append(&mut self, other: &mut Vec<T>)
> ```

However, it seems to me `bar` should be mutable per the keyword provided.

Is it possible to append following a call to `collect`? What's going on here?

- Rust playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=2ea0800ce827fce9b8721255f00e1422

Answer (score 4):

`bar` is indeed mutable, but in the next line it is *immutably* borrowed with `&bar`. You can fix this error by writing

```rust
foo.append(&mut bar);
```